# How to make a House/Email symbol code for html5

Tags: html, icons, symbols

like the house/home symbol is &#8962, I need the most popular symbol codes for a website, like contact us, about us, home, etc.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hmmmmmm  `http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation `&#8962;` (which should really include the semicolon) is just a reference to the character with Unicode code number 8962 in decimal. You can use similar notations for all Unicode characters, so the ultimate reference would be the [Unicode Standard](http://unicode.org/), and in practice you might want to look at the [Code Charts for symbols](http://www.unicode.org/charts/#symbols) there. The symbol denoted by `&#8962;`, U+2302 HOUSE, is in the [Miscellaneous Technical](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2300.pdf) block.

However, most Unicode characters are not supported by most fonts. The real problem with using special characters like “⌂” is with font support and with users’ difficulties in guessing what you mean by such characters (if the users are lucky enough to see them). This is why images are generally recommended for icon-like symbols.